# Programs to combine bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, bookmarks

I've recently been having some issues with xmarks and found that it hasn't been syncing my chromium and firefox bookmarks correctly.

Is there a way to combine the two bookmark HTML files?  Preferably with no overlaps while adding missing bookmarks, but I'd be happy if there was any way I can combine the two bookmark files.

Answer (score 1):

[Firefox Bookmarks.html Merger](http://bookmark-merger.sourceforge.net/) is designed to do just this. To get it running in Ubuntu:

1. Install [python-pyparsing](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-pyparsing/).
2. Download and extract the [Python version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bookmark-merger/files/bookmark-merger/0.2.2/bookmark_merger-0.2.2-src.zip/download) of FBM.
3. Copy the HTML files you want to merge into the extracted folder.
4. Run `python bookmark_merger.py` to automatically detect and merge bookmarks from all HTML files in the current folder.

Should that fail, the author has compiled a [list of software with similar functionality](http://bookmark-merger.sourceforge.net/Links.html) that might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Firefox supports export/import *html* bookmarks *with* tags and annotations starting with version 43 ([my source and test](https://www.diigo.com/outliner/85adjv/Bookmarks-made-usable!-Sync%2C-merge-with-tags-and-more?key=lthwaiel2y)). I like how this allows exporting/importing any bookmarks' *folder(s)* rather than having to replace the whole lot --finally in 2015 :)